# No ByteString deserializer found for type models.MpMember. Try to implement an implicit ByteStringDeserializer for this type

Tags: json, scala, redis, playframework-2.4

I am using etaty rediscala (1.4.2) to connect to Redis in Play 2.4. My code is below:

```
override def getMember(token: String): Future[Option[Member]] = {
  redisClient.get[Member](token)
}
```

However, It shows this error:

*No ByteString deserializer found for type models.Member. Try to implement an implicit ByteStringDeserializer for this type.*

My Member is as follows:

```
case class Member(
  memberId : Long = 0l,
  email : String = "",
  firstName : Option[String] = None,
  lastName : Option[String] = None
)

object Member {
  implicit val memberReads : Reads[Member] = Json.reads[Member]
  implicit val memberWrites : Writes[Member] = Json.writes[Member]
}
```

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Do you want it serialized as JSON in redis? Or something else?

Comment: I want to get the value given the token as the key and convert the value to Scala Member model

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. I convert the Scala object to Json and save to Redis as a string.

```
object Member {
  implicit val byteStringFormatter = new ByteStringFormatter[Member] {
    def serialize(data: Member): ByteString = {
    ByteString(Json.toJson(data).toString)
  }

  def deserialize(bs: ByteString): Member = {
    val s = bs.utf8String
    Json.fromJson[Member](Json.parse(s)).get
  }
}
```

}